# nsstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString frustration?

Tags: xcode, replace, nsstring

I am trying to replace/remove this:

[\"

from string bump3

```
NSString *bump5 = [bump3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\\"" withString:@""];
```

ERROR: missing terminating "" character.

could someone please help me out? My brain is so fried from staring at this screen..

UPDATE:

Figured it out by chance and tried it out!

@"\" is a single backslash
@"\\" is a double backslash

so I used 
          NSString *bump5 = [bump3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\\"" withString:@""];

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should escape both `\` and `"`

```
NSString *bump5 = [bump3 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[\\\"" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this to remove a "-" from a string. 
for example a chain 2773848-2294-2929

```
string = 2773848-2294-2929; 
NSString * replace = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @ "-" withString: @ ""];
```

The result will return the following string: 
277384822942929